# How to add a script to /etc/profile.d so the script runs on every login?

Tags: bash, scripts

I need to make a script that on every login creates folder and subfolder, I have the script written but I don't know how to add it to /etc/profile.d
I have tried to write in /etc/profile.d `source /home/user1/script1.sh` but don't know if this is correct.

Comment: Does this help you?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Answer (score 3):

Just drop the script in `/etc/profile.d`/. You can use mv: `sudo mv ~/script.sh /etc/profile.d/`

** Make sure the file ends with .sh

Comment: I use nano /etc/profile.d/ and then type mv ~/script.sh /etc/profile.d/ but when I try to save it, it says that /etc/profile.d/ is a directory that i cant write in it. Is this wrong what Im doing?

Comment: You don't use `nano`. You enter the above commands as sudo in a shell. /etc/profile.d/ is a directory, not a file

Comment: If this works, please select this as the awnser